# Dynamic table content display with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, google-tv, android-tablelayout

I'm developing for GoogleTV and I have created a dynamic table with 3 columns (using TableLayout), that shows the first 10 results fetched by HTTP from a Website.

As the user starts scrolling through the elements in the table (only rows are selectable, not columns), I want more results (rows) to be fetched and presented instantly (something like Google Reader).

To achieve that I'm using an AsyncTask that fetches more results from the Website, and adds them to the table. The problem is that I find it's behavior a little bit sluggish and unnatural, so I think that I may not be using the right approach.

Is there a better alternative to using TableLayout + AsyncTask? I have chosen TableLayout instead of ListView because I want to display the results in a "table-like" manner so it's easier to absorb the information.

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: What do you mean by "table-like"?

Comment: @Squonk Something like having a row divided in 3 columns e.g. -> Date | Description | Value. It's just for the sake of organization and better presentation to the viewer.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought but wasn't sure. You could simply create a custom "list item" layout and use a `ListView` which should give a similar look and feel.

Comment: Please use traceview to profile your app's performance, see where its spending most of the time. Post the traceview graph here.

Comment: put ur code in ur quest. and there is nothing wrong to use table view with asynctask , asynctask is just a simple thread have no connection how you display your UI part.